# How to track responses from a downstream serive call in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

spring boot application has a lookup service which returns data for symbol provided in request and sends empty response if no information found. My requirement is to track consecutive lookup.service calls and log an exception if all of them returns empty response . Let me know how to approach for solution in spring boot application

Please let me know how to track the service response